# Error downloading image from https urls in c#

Tags: c#, https, download

So, I'm a database administrator, and for odd reasons I have to maintain c# code where I completely suck at this... The code should download images from urls, but when the url is httpS I have an error (no problem at all with simple http urls). I think my predecessor had the same problem since I can see in the code a walkthrough to ignore https:

```
public override Stream GetData(DataManager dm)
{
    try
    {
        // Change SSL checks so that all checks pass
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(delegate { return true; });
        // download image
        return new MemoryStream(dm.Caller.DownloadData(OriginUrl));
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        throw new Exception(String.Format("Failed to download image at this url '{0}'", OriginUrl), e);
    }
}
```

I tried to read some stuff about ServerCertificateValidationCallback but this is my very first code reading in c# and I am completly lost.... Do you know why this code doesn't work with httpS urls? (no problem at all with standard http urls).

Thanks a lot

Comment: *doesn't work* doesn't help us, in what way does it now work? Do you get errors? If so, what are they?

Comment: In addition to what DavidG has already said we also need a bit more detail on the code doing the work. It looks like the actual downloading happens in `dm.Caller.DownloadData(OriginUrl)` but we don't have any idea what that code looks like... Is this a third party library you are using or your own (ie your predecessor's) code or something else?

Comment: Hi DavidG, indeed, sorry it's not very revealing.... The catched exception "e" in the code got message in french "Impossible de lire les données de la connexion de transport : Une connexion existante a dû être fermée par l’hôte distant." which I could approximatively translate by "Impossible to read connection's data, an existing connection might have been closed by the remote host" (probably not the accurate tranlation)...

Comment: Hi Chris, about DownloadData(), the file where I go to when I ask for the function's reference is called System.Net.WebClient.cs and it seems to be a third part library since I don't have any code when I look at his definition, just the line `public byte[] DownloadData(string address);` that's it, no code under

Comment: I forgot to mention something: for the fake https urls (i.e. when in a web browser I replace https by http and the url still hit the website but in a non-secure connexion), then I can download the image, but if I let the S in https, even for fake https url, the DownloadData doesn't work)

Answer (score 0):

```
var req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(OriginUrl);
try
{
  using (var resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse())
  {
    return resp.GetResponseStream();
  }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
  throw new Exception(String.Format("Failed to download image at this url '{0}'", OriginUrl), e);
}
```

Comment: Won't this dispose the `HttpWebResponse` right after returning the stream? Not sure how valid the stream will still be if you dispose its parent object. I'd personally read that stream into a byte array first.

Comment: That said, the data in the question came from something called a `DataManager`, so not sure how relevant any of this is.

Comment: Thanks for the try but I still got the same error message

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this [code](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/forums/c-sharp-webclient-throws-error-while-downloading-a-url-string) below and put it above the line where you download the image:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```